# How to pivot this table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

How would you pivot this table in MySQL? It is ordered by date desc.

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| grpid  | status   | msg       |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|      1 | OK       | text6     |
|      1 | PROGRESS | text5     |
|      1 | PROGRESS | text4     |
|      2 | FAIL     | text3     |
|      2 | PROGRESS | text2     |
|      2 | PROGRESS | text1     |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

to this form:

```
+--------+----------+-------------------+
| grpid  | status   | progress          |
+--------+----------+-------------------+
|      1 | OK       | text4,text5,text6 |
|      2 | FAIL     | text1,text2,text3 |
+--------+----------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a pivot, it's a `GROUP BY` using [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT   grpid,
         GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN status IN ('OK','FAIL') THEN status END) AS status,
         GROUP_CONCAT(msg) AS progress
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY grpid
```

Comment: The thing is, this still returns rows with status=PROGRESS. I need rows only with FAIL or OK status and appropriate grouped PROGRESS msg with the same dialogId in progress column.

Comment: @Mejmo: See my updated answer; this assumes that only one `OK` or `FAIL` status will appear in each group - otherwise, you need to define how you wish for multiple such statuses to be handled.